# Use Dockerhub with Git Submodules

Tags: github, dockerhub

I try to get the auto build feature working for some private github repositories which also have private git submodules. I looked up the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/builds/#creating-an-automated-build) and tried to add the deployment key to the submodule but I got the error "Key is already in use" on GitHub. Then I found out that you can not use one deployment key for multiple github repositories.

So any idea how to solve it? Is there any way to create multiple deployment keys on the dockerhub side?

Thank you in advance and cheers,

Simon

Comment: Question already asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26157290/docker-autobuild-with-git-private-submodule

Comment: thanks for linking the other one!